# Change color of Date and Weather app in Ubuntu 12.04 & Mate

Tags: indicator, customization, mate

I have recentely installed Ubuntu 12.04 and as I am a truly Gnome 2 lover I also switched from Unity to Mate. The font color of the Weather/Date applet is barely visible so I was wondering how I can change it. I Already tried to explore all the options shown in the menu when I right-click on the applet, but apparently there's no such feature. So is there anything I could do in order to customize the font color in order to make the text more readable?

Answer (score 1):

"GNOME Color Chooser" works for me (I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Mate), and it's available in the Ubuntu Software Centre.